# KendoUI MVVM: Reload widgets after router.navigate

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

I would like to know if there's a way to reload KendoUI widgets while using MVVM after you navigate to a script containing one. For example, let's say we have:

```
<div id="view_content"></div>

<script id="index" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <span id="info-notification"
        data-role="notification">
  </span>
</script>
```

And we have a KendoUI router set up to access "/index".

```
var router = new kendo.Router();

router.route("/index", function() {
    var index = new kendo.View('index');

    index.render("#view_content");
});

router.start();
router.navigate("/index");
```

This loads the script into the div with id="view_content". The problem is, the widget isn't reloadad each time "/index" is accessed. The widget is first loaded on `document.ready`, but after calling it again it doesn't reload. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Kendo UI View show() event to reload widgets.

```
<body>
    <div id="application"></div>

    <script id="main" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </script>       

    <script id="index" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <!-- Widgets here -->
    </script>

</body>


var layoutModel = kendo.observable({

});

var indexModel = kendo.observable({

});

var main = new kendo.Layout('main', { 
    model: layoutModel
});

var indexView = new kendo.View('index', {
    model: indexModel,
    show: function () {
        // update widget here
    }
});

var router = new kendo.Router({
    init: function () {
        main.render('#application');
    }
});

var router = new kendo.Router();

router.route("/index", function() {
    main.showIn('#content', indexView);
});

$(function () {
    router.start();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I found a solution.

Comment: I edited my answer. It's now how Kendo SPA application routing works

Comment: A more complete answer than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found. If someone finds a better one, i'll change it. To reload when the View is called, I had to pass the model as a parameter to the View instantiation.

```
var router = new kendo.Router();

router.route("/index", function() {
    var index = new kendo.View('index',{
       model: myNotificationModel //Model to reload instance
    });

    index.render("#view_content");
});

router.start();
router.navigate("/index");
```

For more info, see here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/view#configuration-model